# Explain "[c for c in cEdges if secString in c[0]]"

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

There is an error earlier in the program that I am attempting to find, but was asked to explain what is happening in this part of the code. Below is the code and what I think it is doing, but am unclear on some certain points. Some help in understanding would be greatly appreciated.

```
for title in titles:
    secString = 'sec_%02d' % (title)
    titleCitations = [c for c in cEdges if secString in c[0]]
    intraCitations = [c for c in titleCitations if secString in c[1]]
    print title, len(titleCitations), len(intraCitations), len(titleCitations) - len(intraCitations)
```

First, secString takes the remainder of `'sec_%02d'` with respect to title, (I think this is just finding all strings that have a reference to a title?). It then creates a list titlecitations.

Though I am confused by the bracketed part. If I understand correctly, it takes the cEdge which I believe is just a list of a pairing of numbers from a given US legal code reference i.e. 26 USC 501 becomes just (26, 501), and asks if secString has a value in the c[0] spot.

(This is where I get confused; I am guessing that the c[0] spot maybe corresponds to the 26 in the above example and c[1] would correspond to the 501? Of course I am not even sure if I am understanding the c part correctly.)

Then put it in titlecitations if the c[0] spot is filled. It then creates the intracitations list. This list looks at the titlecitations list and asks if in secString is the c[1] filled and if so put it in this list.

I know there is a problem with something because titlecitations and intracitations appear to be the same list then.

Comment: Maybe you can print out what `cEdges` is, and add a sample so it's clear what's going on?

Comment: `'sec_%02d' % (title)` is string formatting. It inserts `title` into that string, but makes sure that it is padded with a zero: `sec_01`, `sec_99`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
secString = 'sec_%02d' % (title)
```

The `%` operator on a string isn't modulus, it's a formatting operator that behaves like C's printf(). `%02d` is a formatting code that formats `title` as a two-digit number. If `title` is only one digit then it pads it with a `0` (e.g. 9 becomes `09`).

> (This is where I get confused; I am guessing that the c[0] spot maybe corresponds to the 26 in the above example and c[1] would correspond to the 501? Of course I am not even sure if I am understanding the c part correctly.)

That is correct.

```
titleCitations = [c for c in cEdges if secString in c[0]]
```

This searches through the items in `cEdges` and finds ones where the title contains the string `sec_XY` where XY is that two-digit number from earlier.

```
intraCitations = [c for c in titleCitations if secString in c[1]]
```

Now it searches through the things we found in the previous step, again searching for the sub-string `sec_XY`.

The end result is that `intraCitations` contains a list of all the items from `cEdges` where both the first and second item contain the substring `sec_XY`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that in such clear and detailed language and for editing it so that it made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension such as:

```
result = [element for element in list if element in set]
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for element in list:
    if element in set:
        result.append(element)
```

The expression `element in set` (in your case, `c[0]` and `c[1]`) is a membership test, that is True if `element` is contained in the `set`.

As for the specifics of your code, `titleCitations` refers to sources [1] cited by the document `title`. `intraCitations` contains texts that are referenced by (since they are selected from `titleCitations`) and reference `title`.

[1] Actually, `titleCitations` and `intraCitations` both contain the tuples in `c` that satisfy those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
for title in titles:

    secString = 'sec_%02d' % (title)
```

inserts the integer title into this string padded with zeros so that it is two characers long

```
    titleCitations = [c for c in cEdges if secString in c[0]]
```

goes through each element of cEdges (which are themselves lists) and only includes those whose first element contains the string just build

```
    intraCitations = [c for c in titleCitations if secString in c[1]]
```

similarly, builds a sublist of titleCitations which contains those elements whose second element contains secString

```
    print title, len(titleCitations), len(intraCitations), len(titleCitations) - len(intraCitations)
```

prints the title of the book, the number of elements in titlecitations (presumably the number of times this was cited), the number of Intracitations, and the number of titleCitations which aren't intracitations (which suggests one is a subset of the other)